# How to trigger or instrument with edebug programmatically?

Tags: debugging, emacs, elisp

`C-u C-M-x` evaluates a defun form with edebug instrumented. Can I do that programmatically? I want to do that because I want to write an elisp file of the following form:

```
;;; define a function with edebug instrumented.
...


;;; do something that invokes the function with particular arguments.
...
```

then I can run `emacs -q --load` on that elisp file, step through code, get an idea on further investigation on the bug, edit the elisp file in my original emacs session, run `emacs -q --load` on it again, and repeat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `~/test.el`:

```
(defun square (x)
  (* x x))
```

In `~/testtest.el`:

```
(with-current-buffer (find-file-noselect "~/test.el")
  (re-search-forward "square")  
  (edebug-defun))
(square 5)
```

In `bash`:

```
emacs -q -l ~/testtest.el
```